# Why is opening files with my discord bot causing unintended event loop behaviour?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py, python-asyncio, nextcord

I'm creating a personal discord bot to make a daily task of mine easier, which involves taking some readings daily. My chosen method is storing my user data in directories as plain text. So the directory structure looks something like this:

`Logs/year/month/day/data.txt`

However, I am facing a strange issue that seems to interfere with the way the event loop is executed. It happens at this part of my code:

```py
async def GapFunc(year, month, day, path):
    DirArray = os.listdir(path)  # Get directories
    print("Enter GapFunc")
    Array = []
    for i in DirArray:  # Loop through directories
        Array.append(int(i))  # Append it to new array as an integer
    Array.sort()  # Sort the array numerically

    previous = None
    for num in Array:
        print(previous)
        if previous == None:  # This function works by comparisons, and there is nothing to compare at the first iteration
            previous = num
            continue
        result = num - previous  # Compare previous number with current number
        if result > 1:  # If the result is more than 1, there is a gap.
            print("Gap detected between %s and %s" % (str(previous), str(num)))
            file = open(path + str(previous) + "/data.txt", 'r')  # Open the file to print the data so I can deal with it later on
            print(file.readline())
            file.close()
        previous = num
        await asyncio.sleep(0)  # Let another task in the event loop work in case this takes a long time
```

This function checks for gaps in my data entries by listing the directories named by the day's number, storing them in an array, sorting it, and checking if there are any interment gaps.

The problem with this is, when I read the files, the code seems to go haywire. After the file is opened like this `file = open(path + str(previous) + "/data.txt", 'r')`, any subsequent code (such as a simple print statement) that comes after the reader gets ignored and the loop continues.

Additionally, it also causes the other function this was called from to loop, which is not supposed to happen as far as I'm concerned, as it has a task decorator setting it to loop every 60 minutes. Here is the code the above function is called from:

```py
@tasks.loop(minutes=60)
async def Notifier():
    date = datetime.now()
    year = date.strftime("%Y/")
    month = date.strftime("%m/")
    day = date.strftime("%d/")
    if not os.path.exists(Data + year):  # Do a bunch of directory checking
        os.makedirs(Data + year)
    if not os.path.exists(Data + year + month):
        os.makedirs(Data + year + month)
    if not os.path.exists(Data + year + month + day):
        os.makedirs(Data + year + month + day)
    if not os.path.exists(Data + year + month + day + "Data.txt"):
        ChannelObject = client.get_channel(NOTIFS_ID)  # Notify myself
        await ChannelObject.send("Hey, you have not submitted today's readings!")

    # At the end, check for any gaps in data entries by calling this function.        
    await GapFunc(year.replace("/", ""), month.replace("/", ""), day.replace("/", ""), Data + year + month)
```

Here you can see the notification I have made for myself running over and over, which proves what I'm saying:

[image]

As a test, I removed the `open()` function lines from the bot code while leaving everything else, and this fixes everything. The task loop runs every sixty minutes as intended, and the event loop behaves normally.

**Update**:
I found the fix and the reason, but not the exact cause. The reason this is happening is because the file reader cannot find the file specified and throws a completely quiet exception, hence the code being skipped. But *why* this causes the function this was called from to loop as well is a mystery to me.

With a Try/Catch blocK:

```
print("About to read")
try:
    with open(path + str(num) + "/data.txt", 'r') as d:
        print(d.readline().strip())
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
print("Finished trying reading")
```

It outputs:

```
About to read
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'MeterData/2022/04/11/data.txt'
Finished trying reading
```

And if I do it without the Try/Catch Block

```
print("About to read")
with open(path + str(num) + "/data.txt", 'r') as d:
    print(d.readline().strip())
print("Finished trying reading")
```

It outputs:

```
About to read
Entered main task loop
```

As I explained, it crashes quitely and goes back to the function it was called from (defined as Notifier in my code, which loops every 60mins) to start it all over again

I'm not 100% sure why this happens. It might be a bug in the file reader combined with the behavior of nextcord's event loop that causes this problem?